# Database structure in a Rails project and keep track of migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

So after alot of reading i found out that i dont need to plan my database ahead. I just start working on the application and do migrations on every change.

So for example if I decide to add something I add it via migration. Then on another migration I delete it for some reason. And in the end I decide to get it back. After a short time there will be a mess of migrations.

How do I keep track of them? Wouldnt be easier to think of the database structure in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails way is to do everything via migrations. As per your scenario it would be like:

```
migration1 #add column A
migration2 #remove column A
migration3 #add column A again
```

It seems like there are lots of migrations, but in practical scenario it will keep your database changes clean. Because at any given time when you do:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Rails will run only the pending migrations.

And at any given time you will see the `db/schema.rb` file with all the migrates and latest migration number as the version.

Having said that, if you want to revert a migration there are commands like `rollback` commands. [Read more about migrations here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can see your database structure inside `db/schema.rb` which will show you all the tables, columns and indexes currently in your app.

Not as helpful if you're constantly changing a column, but you can also run `rake db:migrate:status` which will output a list of all migrations, and tell you whether they've been run or not.